# Lower caption for beside caption with floatrow package

Tags: floats, captions, floatrow

I'm using the `floatrow` package for float and caption design. I like the prospect of captions beside figures/tables; however, when I vertically position them to the top, I think it would look better if the caption (including the label) were a few pts lower. Any suggestion on how to achieve this? I've looked through the `floatrow` documentation and don't see an obvious solution. The `\floatcapbesidemargins` option sets left/right margins. Adding `vspace` in the first argument of floatbox wont do the trick (EDIT as the table then protrudes into the top `\rule` I've drawn), so perhaps temporarily re-defining `caption` would be smarter?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\rule{\linewidth}{0.4pt}

\floatbox[\capbeside\thisfloatsetup{capbesideposition={left,top},capbesidesep=columnsep}]{table}
{\caption{I would like this caption, including the label, to be slightly lower. Say a few pts}\label{test}}%
{\begin{tabular}{ll}\toprule
column 1a & column 2a \\
column 1b & column 2b \\
column 1c & column 2c\\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}

\rule{\linewidth}{0.4pt}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can fool latex, making it believe is less high than it really is  with the optional argument of `\raisebox`, and add a \vertical spacing before the table to compensate:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\noindent\hrulefill
\vskip 1ex
\floatbox[\capbeside\thisfloatsetup{capbesideposition={left,top},capbesidesep=columnsep}]{table}
{\caption{I would like this caption, including the label, to be slightly lower. Say a few pts}\label{test}}%
{\raisebox{0pt}[0.8\height]{\begin{tabular}{ll}\toprule
column 1a & column 2a \\
column 1b & column 2b \\
column 1c & column 2c\\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}}

\noindent\hrulefill

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't the spacing then depend on the height of the table? What if I wanted, say 3 pt for every caption.

Comment: I can answer my comment above: use the `calc` package, and `\height-3pt` for example

Comment: That's right. You also can use, without loading calc, `[\dimexpr \height-3pt]` (I would rather subtract  a fixed width measured in `ex`, so would produce the same layout when you change the font size in the document).

Answer (score 0):

Just add below code to your mwe.

```
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Similar result you as with @Bernard answer (+1) you can obtain by the following trick:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]{1-2]

\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}
\floatbox[\capbeside\thisfloatsetup{capbesideposition={left,top},capbesidesep=columnsep}]{table}
{
 \caption{\protect\rule{0pt}{2.8ex}
          I would like this caption, including the label, to be slightly lower. Say a few pts}
 \label{test}}%
{
\begin{tabular}{ll}\toprule
column 1a & column 2a \\
column 1b & column 2b \\
column 1c & column 2c \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}

\lipsum[1]{3-4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** Solution is now rewritten. Caption is mowed down by inserting `\protect\rule{0pt}{2.8ex}` before text in the caption.

I wonder, what is purpose of rules above and below floatbox. They have strong influence on space above and below floatbox.

Comment: Notice how the table protrudes into the top horizontal rule? That's why I mentioned adding `\vspace` won't do the trick. Also why I added the rules.

Comment: I suppose adding `\vskip3pt` could be used above the floatbox to compensate

Comment: @likethevegetable, I know this, but forgot to add ... see edited answer.

Comment: @likethevegetable, I edit my answer again. See, if now better fit your expectations.

Comment: I was thinking about adding an invisible rule too.. would there be implications for the List of Tables in the ToC, though?

Comment: @likethevegetable,  you right. But this can be eliminated by adding caption for LoT in square brackets, for example: `\caption[This caption text will appear in LoT]
         {\protect\rule{0pt}{2.8ex}
          I would like this caption, including the label, to be slightly lower. Say a few pts}`.